# Correct way to define onItemClick behaviour for multiple lists in one activity?

Tags: java, android, listview

I've seen multiple questions about displaying multiple listviews in one activity, but my question relates to the onClick behaviour of the two. I set up two listviews besides one another, and dynamically populated them - this works fine. The issue is when it comes to setting onClick behaviour for the two lists. With my current code the second list opens the desired activity on top of the activity that would have been opened if the same item in the first list were clicked. Thus when the user goes back it goes to the wrong activity as the back stack is wrong.

My code for defining the onItemClick behaviour is here:

```
//make listview items respond to clicks and open relevant activity
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // selected item
            String standard = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(SubjectActivity.this, StandardInfoActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("standard", standard);
            i.putExtra("subject", subjectId);
            i.putExtra("subjectName", subject);
            i.putExtra("level", level);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    gradeView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent2, View view,
                                int position, long id2) {
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent j = new Intent(SubjectActivity.this, AddGradeActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            j.putExtra("subjectId", subjectId);
            j.putExtra("position", position);
            j.putExtra("level", level);
            j.putExtra("subject", subject);
            startActivity(j);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

My guess is that because I'm defining the same function for both, it's being called twice with the click on the second list, once for the first list and then again for the desired list. What would be the correct way to define the behaviour of the two lists in this case?

EDIT: Code used to set up adapters:

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = myDb.getStandards(subjectId);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.subject_list_item, mArrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    ArrayList<String> gradeList = myDb.getGrades(subjectId);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.subject_list_item, gradeList);
    gradeView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
```

Comment: I can not see the part where you say: "because I'm defining the same function for both, it's being called twice with the click on the second list".

Comment: @sebasira they're both called onItemClick

Comment: I think they both override the onItemClick of the interface but they are two different implementations of it so they are not related at all

Comment: Can you show how are you defining and setting the adapters on the list?

Comment: @Sebasira added

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see why you get that behavior... You have two separate adapters on two separate listview with two separate click listeners. I don't want to waste your time, but any chance you can make a small demo to reproduce it and share it? Maybe github? Or here if it's not too big.

Answer (score 0):

Calling finish() like that will lead to onDestroy() being called for the current activity ( https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy ), which will take it off of the back stack.  So I think it's possible you're going back and just getting a surprising result.

One way you can see if you're really triggering both onItemClickListeners is you can add temporary debug messages to both and then see what kind of output you get.  Like, on one you can try `Log.d("ClickListener", "lv was clicked");` and on the other try `Log.d("ClickListener", "gradeView was clicked");` and then check Logcat and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface in your Adapter. Then You can override methods in Your activity.
Interface:

```
   public interface ItemClickAdapterListener {
        void itemClick(View v, int position);
    }
```

Item Click:

```
 viewHolder.llayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onClickListener.itemClick(view,position);
                }
            });
```

Activity code. Create Adapter object like this

```
YourAdpter adapter= new YourAdpter(new YourAdapter.ItemClickAdapterListener() {
  @Override
                public void itemClick(View v, int position) {

                }
}):
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a little new to Java and I'm having some difficulty figuring out how that fits together. Could you possibly put it in context a little? My listviews are called lv and gradeview. Does the interface come outside the main method?